# Count Entities in a Many to Many relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I have a User entity as follows:

```
public class User {
  public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Each user can have one or more roles. I need to count the number of Users per Role.

If a user has the roles Editor and Member then it will count 1 for Editor and 1 for Member.

How can I do this?

Thnak You
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it ... I was trying to do this through users but I went for this:

Dictionary count = context.Roles.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Users.Count }).ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Count)

What do you think? Any suggestion to improve it?

Thank You,
Miguel